# how to find list of all words from a given array of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve a word puzzle with 5 alphabets, which can have 3 , 4 and 5 letter words . how should I write my algorithm to make this happen?

I have tried making a 5 nested loops to go through the characters of array and then adding all the loops , it works for small words but crashes due to time complexity.

```
const addandlog = (array) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; i < array.length; k++) {

        console.log(array[i] + array[j] + array[k]);

      }
    }
  }
}
addandlog(['A', 'G', 'R', 'N', 'D']);
```

I expect the output to be all the words that can be made and not just the dictionary words

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: it probably crashed cause you have i < array.length in third loop instead of k < array.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative approach by taking an array of arrays with the wanted items.

```js
function getWords(letters, length) {
    return Array
        .from({ length })
        .fill(letters)
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(a => a.join(''))
}

console.log(getWords(['A', 'G', 'R', 'N', 'D'], 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you also tell me how to output the words that are valid or in dictionary?

Comment: for this task, you need the dictionary and check against.